# Python: Import script in a way that doesn't require writing its name before the class name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file called `lib.py` which contains custom types I use in my project, for example an x + y + z vector registered as `vec3`:

```
class vec3:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, z: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Whenever I use it I of course use `import lib` at the beginning of my other script. What I don't like is having to always call it as `lib.vec3` instead of just `vec3` the same way I would builtin types like `float`. Is there a way to write the import command to treat classes as if they're defined locally so I can use only the class name?

Comment: `from lib import vec3`. Read the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Thanks! What I want is `from lib import *` since I plan on using almost everything there usually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @beruic for the response in the comment. What I want is `from lib import vec3`, though in my case I'm using `from lib import *` as I see no reason to rule out any of the types I'm using. I saw that notation but thought it's to filter the contents of the imported script rather that make its classes available directly.